# Why I can't use asyncTask

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

[image: old library]

[image: async task]

Android AsyncTask is Deprecated. so I can't use this library. I searched other ways to take data from the Internet but I couldn't. How can I write it in other ways?

Comment: please add your code instead of picture to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this library is old. And android studio doesn't support this anymore. I remake your project. You can search Volley or Retrofit fot take data from the Internet. You can look at my github repo -> https://github.com/yagmurerdogan/WeatherApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tutorials/weatherapp/MainActivity.kt

Comment: Thank you! You've been very helpful!